# Raw use of parameterized with ObservableList and TableColums

Tags: java, javafx, tablecolumn, observablelist

Hi can someone show to in this code how, to put right Types. I am tryed many ways but.. So how to put right types in the ObservablelIst and TableColumn. I meen <S,T>

```
    **ObservableList data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();**

 
        List<String> newColumnsString = adminHallintaController.admincomboValidator(tablenameid);


            **var col = new TableColumn**(newColumnsString.get(i));
            **col.setCellValueFactory**((Callback<CellDataFeatures<**ObservableList,** String>, ObservableValue<String>>) param -> new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString()));
            hallintaTable.getColumns().addAll(col);
        }

        while(rsHaku.next()){
            **ObservableList<String> row** = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); --Here
            for(int i=1 ; i<=rsHaku.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
                row.add(rsHaku.getString(i));
            }
            **data.add(row);**
        }
        

private static void addEditButtonToTable(TableView<Object> hallintaTable, String tablenameid) {
    **TableColumn col_editaction = new TableColumn<>("Muokkaa");
    TableColumn col_delaction = new TableColumn<>("Poista");**
    hallintaTable.getColumns().addAll(col_editaction, col_delaction);

    **col_editaction.setCellValueFactory**((Callback<CellDataFeatures<Record, Boolean>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>) p -> new SimpleBooleanProperty(p.getValue() != null));
    **col_delaction.setCellValueFactory**((Callback<CellDataFeatures<Record, Boolean>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>) p -> new SimpleBooleanProperty(p.getValue() != null));
    //Adding the Button to the cell
    **col_editaction.setCellFactory**((Callback<TableColumn<Record, Boolean>, TableCell<Record, Boolean>>) p -> new editButtonCell(hallintaTable, tablenameid));
    **col_delaction.setCellFactory**((Callback<TableColumn<Record, Boolean>, TableCell<Record, Boolean>>) p -> new delButtonCell(hallintaTable, tablenameid));
```

Comment: A `TableView<S>` has a collection of rows, each of which is represented by an object of type `S`. Each column in the table is a `TableColumn<S,T>`, where `S` is the same type as the `TableView`, and `T` (which can be different for each column) is the type of the value displayed in each cell in that column. It looks (from your cell value factories) like you are trying to make both your columns `TableColumn<Record, Boolean>`, which means that you should have a `TableView<Record>`, `ObservableList<Record> data`, and you should be creating a `Record` instance for each row.

Comment: java naming conventions please

Comment: Thanks for your help! When i will put - ObservableList<Record> data  and then i need change  -- data.add((Record) row);  problem will be  - message class com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper cannot be cast to class java.lang.Record

Comment: @HeikkiTurunen Why are you making `row` a list? It should be a `Record`

Comment: Actually, wait. `java.lang.Record`? That makes no sense. I assumed you had created your own `Record` class. What are you actually trying to do here?